# Try to build vim and test is stuck on "Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified"

Tags: unit-testing

I am trying to build vim from source and the build test is stuck with a message as follows: "Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified". This message appeared frequently in the tests, but when it reached Test_nb_quit_with_conn() it gave that message and has now hung for a long time (5-10 minutes).

Comment: This may have better luck with the vim repo or mailing list